# Edit core data through table view

Tags: ios, swift

My app has two view controllers -  ViewController and ListViewController. There is a form to be completed on the View Controller and the ListView controller gives a table view of all the completed forms. I am at the point where I can enter data, delete data, but I am struggling with coding editing functionality. Note my for is created using Eureka. Below is the code that loads the information into core data.

I continue to try and find an answer to this. I have watched many YouTube videos, but it appears they are dated and I cannot map over to the new version of swift.

attempt using segue: Get error "Type 'OTSProcessConfirmations.Type' has no subscript members" on the last line of code

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "editOTS"
    {
        let v = segue.destination as! ViewController

        let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let row = indexpath?.row

        v.PC = OTSProcessConfirmations[row!]

    }

var branch: String = ""
var enterDate: Date? = nil
var OTSQ1: Bool = false
var OTSQ2: Bool = false
var OTSQ3: Bool = false
var OTSQ4: Bool = false
var OTSQ5: Bool = false
var OTSQ6: Bool = false
var OTSQ7: Bool = false
var OTSQ8: Bool = false
var OTSQ9: Bool = false
var OTSQ10: Bool = false
var OTSQ11: Bool = false
var OTSQ12: Bool = false
var OTSQ13: Bool = false
var OTSQ14: Bool = false

var processConfirmation: OTSProcessConfirmations?

@IBAction func BtnSave(_ sender: Any) {



    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let ots = OTSProcessConfirmations(context:context)

    ots.branch = branch
    ots.enterDate = enterDate
    ots.otsq1 = OTSQ1
    ots.otsq2 = OTSQ2
    ots.otsq3 = OTSQ3
    ots.otsq4 = OTSQ4
    ots.otsq5 = OTSQ5
    ots.otsq6 = OTSQ6
    ots.otsq7 = OTSQ7
    ots.otsq8 = OTSQ8
    ots.otsq9 = OTSQ9
    ots.otsq10 = OTSQ10
    ots.otsq11 = OTSQ11
    ots.otsq12 = OTSQ12
    ots.otsq13 = OTSQ13
    ots.otsq14 = OTSQ14


    // Save the data to coredata

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

**ListView Controller code**

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var OTSs : [OTSProcessConfirmations] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // get the data from core data

        getData()


        /// reload the table view

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        <#code#>
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return OTSs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        let ots = OTSs[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = ots.branch!


        return cell
    }
    func getData() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            OTSs = try context.fetch(OTSProcessConfirmations.fetchRequest())

        }
        catch{
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        if editingStyle == .delete {

            let ots = OTSs[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(ots)

            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do {
                OTSs = try context.fetch(OTSProcessConfirmations.fetchRequest())
            }
            catch {
                print("Fetching Failed")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear.

Rather than the Core Data entity `OTSProcessConfirmations` you have to get the instance for the selected row from the data source array.

```
v.PC = OTSs[row!]
```

By the way your code is very hard to read. Please conform to the naming guidelines that class and struct names start with a capital letter and function and variable names start with a lowercase letter. This can avoid such kind of errors.

Further please use more descriptive names than a single letter or an abbreviation especially if you are going to share the code.

Finally classes, structs and Core Data entities are supposed to be named in singular form (`OTSProcessConfirmation`).

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. I’m going to restart my project and work to follow proper naming guidelines. Is there a reference for newbies anyone can recommend?

Comment: The most comprehensive reference is the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1)